# Programatically open a application in c# windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to do a alarm clock app in wp7.

Then i wanted something like **when the user click on the dismiss alarm button it will programatically launch a specify mobile application**.

Is that possible??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notifications (assumming that's how you're showing your alarm) are able to launch the applciation they were created from.

It is not possible to lauch other applications from within your app. With the exception of those launched by the built in Launchers and choosers.

Comment: Then is there a example to see how is it coded for the button control to launch the application?

Comment: @ben If you just tap on the text of the notification or reminder it should open the app.

Comment: Oh i didnt realize it can be clicked. Thank. By the way can the notification button be configured?? Something when click on the button it will show some message box

Comment: @ben ther's no event to specifically capture this scenario but you could infer it by adding something to the querystring passed to the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.reminder.navigationuri(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: By the way for alarm notification it does not have the navigation uri method right?